# Data Slices in ADF do not execute sequentially in time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple activities in a pipeline and they have dependencies among themselves. When I set my pipeline start date in the past, my data slices set do not execute sequentially in time. To elaborate:

Let's say I have two activities A1 & A2. A2 has a dependency on A1 and takes much longer to execute than A1. Let's say I upload my pipeline today with a start date of 3 days back in time (d-3). I'd like my activities to follow the sequence as:

A1(d-3) -> A2(d-3) -> A1(d-2) -> A2(d-2) -> A1(d-1) -> A2(d-1)  ->

But in practice I see that all data slices of A1 have been executed whereas A2(d-3) is still in progress. 
How to enforce that all data slices for a particular date are completed before slices of the next day are taken up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to accomplish this, because every data slice is independent on others and should not depend on previous executions. If you make you query correctly, the execution order should not matter.